# Primes as sum of squares

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ a prime of the form $24k+q$ where $q$ belongs to the set $\{\pm1,\pm5,\pm7,\pm11\}$. It is well known that all the forms $24k+1$, $24k+5$, $24k-7$, $24k-11$ can be written as the sum of two squares, let's say generically $x^2+y^2$. The forms $24k-5$ and $24k+11$, instead, can be written as $x^2+2y^2$. Finally, the form $24k+7$ as $x^2+3y^2$. But what we can say about the form $24k-1$? Does it exist a proof of the impossibility of writing $24k-1$ as a sum similar to the previous? I think it's not possible, but if we accept a third addend in the sum, we can probably write $$24k-1=x^2+y^2+2\cdot(3\cdot(2l+1))^2$$ for some integer $l\ge0$. More, I conjecture that in the previous identity the sum $x^2+y^2$ is always a prime (of the form $4m+1$), except for the following primes $p$ $$239=10^2+11^2+2\cdot3^2$$ $$383=13^2+14^2+2\cdot3^2$$ $$1367=23^2+26^2+2\cdot9^2$$ Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Note that $x^2 - 2 y^2$ integrally represents all (positive) primes of type $8n - 1.$  Let's see, you want primes (perhaps all such numbers?) 24k - 1 to be written as $x^2 + y^2 + 18 z^2$ with $z$ odd. I don't believe this ternary form to be regular, let me check... meanwhile, there are plenty of almost regular positive ternaries.

Comment: Alright, 1,1,18 is not regular. that need not prevent your 24k-1 being presented. As an example, the irregular ternary $x^2 + y^2 + 10 z^2$ integrally represents all $6n+5.$ It may take me a while to check and prove things with your 1,1,18. Meanwhile, here is a whole bunch of stuff on positive ternaries: http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADDED: bad news, as $x^2 + y^2 + 18 z^2$ does not integrally represent $95 = 96-1,$ it is likely to be hard to impossible to prove that it represents all other $24k-1.$ I have never tried to show that a ternary represents all primes in an arithmetic progression, there may be some sort of lucky trick. For example, it might be possible to prove that 1,1,18 represents all 24k - 1 that are NOT divisible by 5; this would include all your primes.

From one of my tables, here is a first impression of your 1,1,18: it is not allowed to represent any $\pm 3 \pmod 9$ or $4^k (16n - 2).$ It is allowed to represent your 24k -1, and every one of your numbers is integrally represented by at least one of $x^2 + y^2 + 18 z^2$ and $2x^2 + 2 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 2zx.$ Most (permitted)numbers are represented by both forms.

```
=====Discriminant  72  ==Genus Size==   2
   Discriminant   72
  Spinor genus misses     no exceptions
        72:    1     1         18      0    0    0 vs. s.g.   7  11  95  151  589
        72:    2     2          5      0    2    0 vs. s.g.   1  single squareclass
--------------------------size 2
The 150 smallest numbers represented by full genus
     1     2     4     5     7     8     9    10    11    13
    16    17    18    19    20    22    23    25    26    27
    28    29    31    32    34    35    36    37    38    40
    41    43    44    45    47    49    50    52    53    54
    55    58    59    61    63    64    65    67    68    70
    71    72    73    74    76    77    79    80    81    82
    83    85    86    88    89    90    91    92    95    97
    98    99   100   101   103   104   106   107   108   109
   112   113   115   116   117   118   119   121   122   124
   125   127   128   130   131   133   134   135   136   137
   139   140   143   144   145   146   148   149   151   152
   153   154   155   157   160   161   162   163   164   166
   167   169   170   171   172   173   175   176   178   179
   180   181   182   185   187   188   189   191   193   194
   196   197   198   199   200   202   203   205   207   208

The 150 smallest numbers NOT represented by full genus
     3     6    12    14    15    21    24    30    33    39
    42    46    48    51    56    57    60    62    66    69
    75    78    84    87    93    94    96   102   105   110
   111   114   120   123   126   129   132   138   141   142
   147   150   156   158   159   165   168   174   177   183
   184   186   190   192   195   201   204   206   210   213
   219   222   224   228   231   237   238   240   246   248
   249   254   255   258   264   267   270   273   276   282
   285   286   291   294   300   302   303   309   312   318
   321   327   330   334   336   339   345   348   350   354
   357   363   366   372   375   376   381   382   384   390
   393   398   399   402   408   411   414   417   420   426
   429   430   435   438   440   444   446   447   453   456
   462   465   471   474   478   480   483   489   492   494
   498   501   504   507   510   516   519   525   526   528

Disc: 72
==================================


        72:    1     1         18      0    0    0
misses, compared with full genus
            7           11           95          151          589



        72:    2     2          5      0    2    0
misses, compared with full genus
    1:      1
```